# Which Mac address should be used in Ethernet Header?

Tags: ethernet, lan, mac-address, wan

Consider that we are working on a Local Area (LAN). In this case, I use the mac address of the destination device for destination MAC address for ethernet header. This is working.

But, I don't know, which Mac address should be used on Global Network (WAN).

- Mac address of the Router of destination device?
- Mac address of the Router of source device?
- Mac address of the destination device?

I draw a schema to explain my question. But I'd needed at least 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: The MAC address typically won't be used on WAN connections. Read for example this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14241674/133645 (that includes this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)

Comment: In a WAN a packet will be handled by many different devices. The destination MAC address that's used at the start, is the MAC address of the next hop device (in a LAN your default gateway). When you default gateway forwards the package to the next hop, it will use that next hops MAC address as the destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several combinations and I realized that in Wide Area, the destination Mac address in the ethernet header should be the default gateway's Mac address of the device. In my stuation, it was "Mac address of the Router of source device".